# A little problem with Terminal

Tags: command-line, 16.04

I've just download flash player on my Ubuntu and right now I'm stuck with it. I don't know what to do next. Please help me.

Here is a screen-shot of my problem:
[image: Here's the link to my problem]

Answer (score 2):

To copy that file to the `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins` directory, the correct command should be

```
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
```

(note the `/` before `usr`)

If you accidentally screwed up your /usr directory though, things could get more complicated.

You shouldn't have to (and really shouldn't) download and install the Flash plugin manually; Ubuntu has a Flash plugin installer that does all the work.

Comment: So to avoid things get more complicated because I'm just a new Linux user,  is there any other way for me to use Terminal more effectively?

Comment: @HàVũ One suggestion would be to use completion — when typing filenames or packages names (with `apt` or `apt-get`), press the `TAB` key and it tries to autocomplete/provide suggestions.